# How to return class variable as a dict?

Tags: python, oop, python-class

I am trying to write a method in my class and trying to return as `dict`.

```
class Test(object):
    location = 'Dhaka'

    @classmethod
    def get_items(cls):
        items = dict()

        for item in cls:
            items[item.name] = item.value

        return items


class NewTest(Test):
    lat = 4444
```

and I am trying to get the result following this:

```
print(NewTest.get_items())
{'location': 'Dhaka', 'lat': 4444}
```

But returning error like that type can't be iterated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can look through the contents of applying `dir()` to the class to get all its attributes, but need some way to filter out things with special names while looking for class variables. A fairly fast way to do that would be with regular expression pattern matching to recognize them. You'll also need filter out *callable values* like the `get_items()` classmethod.

Doing both is illustrated below.

```
import re

DUNDER = re.compile(r'^__[^\d\W]\w*__\Z', re.UNICODE)  # Special method names.


class Test(object):
    location = 'Dhaka'

    @classmethod
    def get_items(cls):
        is_special = DUNDER.match  # Local var to speed access.
        items = {}

        for name in dir(cls):
            if not is_special(name):
                value = getattr(cls, name)
                if not callable(value):
                    items[name] = value

        return items


class NewTest(Test):
    lat = 4444


print(NewTest.get_items())  # -> {'lat': 4444, 'location': 'Dhaka'}
```

Answer (score 0):

The class can't be iterated; its `__dict__` attribute can, though.

```
@classmethod
def get_items(cls):
    items = dict()

    # Loop defined enums
    for item in cls.__dict__:
        if item == "__module__":
            continue
        items[item] = cls.__dict__[item]

    # return in tuple
    return items
```

You'll want to do some filtering on the keys of the dict, as the class may have additional attributes aside from the ones you create.

Comment: Thanks but the problem is, it returning this:  

{'__module__': '__main__', 'lat': 4444, '__doc__': None}  


__module__:__main like this, i dont need this,

Comment: And it is good removing the unwanted key again, I guess there are another way to do this

Comment: delte your answer, it's not soled my problem

Comment: I think `vars(cls)` should be preferred but I'm not sure if it works in a classmethod.

Comment: @howrecepes That's why I said "you'll want to do some filtering". It's probably easier to be explicit and just create a dict that contains the keys you *want*, rather than trying to identify the ones you *don't*.

Comment: vars works in classmethod but unwanted key yet, if i filter, it will be slow a bit i think